# How to write to an xml file while the program in running?

Tags: java, xml

I've managed to write to an xml file in the way that I want, but it will only update the file after the program is exited. I'd like for the file to update as soon as a button is pressed.

Here is the code I'm using. It's run when a JButton is clicked on.

```
    try {
        documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        xmlDoc = documentBuilder.parse(Reminders.class.getResourceAsStream("Reminders.xml"));
    } catch(ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Node rNode = xmlDoc.getChildNodes().item(0);
    Node remindersNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("reminders").item(0);
    Node newReminder = xmlDoc.createElement("r" + remindersNode.getChildNodes().getLength()/2);

    // Elements are created and put together
    // Redacted because they take up too much space

    OutputFormat outFormat = new OutputFormat(xmlDoc);
    outFormat.setIndenting(true);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("src/virtualagenda/Reminders.xml");
        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outStream, outFormat);
        serializer.serialize(xmlDoc);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

    }catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Is the file to be _updated_ or _created_? Can you see it being created when it's not there before?

Comment: It's being updated. I have to create the file manually and add a few nodes before it will work.

Comment: But the source and target paths are different: "Reminders.xml" vs "src/virtualagenda/Reminders.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

to force the writing?

Comment: I added it and the same thing happened.

Comment: Can you make sure the lines _are_ executed twice (or more times) - assuming the button can be clicked more than once? I bet there is something about handling clicks, not flushing the outStream contents.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I had the program print something right after those lines and it printed it whenever I pressed the button.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Just for test sake, can you add a random prefix to the filename each time, so it would generate a new one each run? That would allow to confirm (or rule out) a few options.

Comment: It is creating one each time.

Comment: OK then how do you check that it has been updated or not? I mean, maybe there is a delay/cache getting in the way to _read_ the file when you do.

Comment: It will add a new <r#> tag after the program closes.

Comment: I have the file open in netbeans and it automatically adds it as soon as I close the program.

Comment: Close it in netbeans, open the xml in a simplest text editor. Close, reopen after each click.

Answer (score 1):

You have to flush the `FileOutputStream`.

```
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("src/virtualagenda/Reminders.xml");
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outStream, outFormat);
serializer.serialize(xmlDoc);
outStream.flush()
```

Or if you are done with the stream, just close it using `outStream.close()`